# How do I show that $\frac {|s|} {\sigma} \leq \sqrt {1 + \tan \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )}\ $?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Show that in the region $\left \{s\ \big |\ \left |\arg \left (s \right ) \right | \leq \frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right \}$ $$\frac {|s|} {\sigma} \leq \sqrt {1 + \tan \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )}$$ where $\mathfrak {R} (s) = \sigma$ and $0 \lt \delta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}.$

What I did is the following $:$

Let $\mathfrak {I} (s) = \tau.$ Then $$\begin {align*} \frac {|s|} {\sigma} & = \frac {\sqrt {\sigma^2 + \tau^2}} {\sigma} \\ & = \sqrt {1 + \left (\frac {\tau} {\sigma} \right )^2} \\ & \leq \sqrt {1 + \tan^2 \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )} \end{align*}$$ The last equality follows from the fact that $-\frac {\pi} {2} \lt - \frac {\pi} {2} + \delta \leq \arg \left (s \right ) \leq \frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \lt \frac {\pi} {2}$ and $\tan x$ is increasing on $\left (-\frac {\pi} {2}, \frac {\pi} {2} \right ).$ But the problem is that the last inequality what I have obtained doesn't match properly with that of the desired inequality. Did I make any mistake here? Could anybody please check it once?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the question, i.e. the tan should be squared.

Comment: @Tavish is it possible to draw a counter-example then? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. You can construct a counter example to the other inequality by choosing $s=\sigma + i\tau$ such that $\arg(s) = \pi/2 - \delta > \pi/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation of
$$
 \frac {|s|} {\sigma} \leq \sqrt {1 + \tan^2 \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )} 
$$
is correct, and equality holds if $|\arg(s)| = \pi/2 - \delta$.

If $|\arg(s)| = \pi/2 - \delta$ and $0 <\delta < \pi/4$ then
$$
\frac {|s|} {\sigma} = \sqrt {1 + \tan^2 \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )} > \sqrt {1 + \tan \left (\frac {\pi} {2} - \delta \right )} 
$$
so that the first inequality does *not* hold in general.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Your cooperation is warmly appreciated. Thank in very much.